# Equivalent of "to be clothed" for plumage

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice

Context: I'm writing a book half from the perspective of a non-human character, who has grown up in a non-human culture and civilization. So, the language she uses to describe the events and setting should reflect her non-human background.

Problem: Since these non-human characters (harpies: half human half bird) do not wear clothes, she would not use words such as "clothed" to describe something, even metaphorically. For example, she would not say that "the low hills are clothed in evergreen" because that metaphor would mean nothing to her. *In short, I'm looking for an equivalent of "clothed" for plumage.*

My reject box:

The hatchling is **feathered** with soft down. / The low hills are **feathered** with evergreen. (Closest, but implies a very light cover or a fringe.)

The hatchling is **bedecked** with soft down. / The low hills are **bedecked** with evergreen. (Implies extravagance.)

The hatchling is **garbed** with soft down. / The low hills are **garbed** in evergreen. (Same problem as with "clothed.")

The hatchling is **covered** with soft down. / The low hills are **covered** with evergreen. (Not specific or vivid).

The hatchling is **plumed** with soft down. / The low hills are **plumed** with evergreen. (A twisted usage, but it could work in a fictional story.)

I feel like there must be a word for this. Thanks in advance for any ideas!

Comment: How about "enveloped"

Comment: "To enwrap" is sufficiently poetic in its transferred meaning.

Comment: How about "arrayed"?

Comment: *Arrayed* is good, like the lilies of the field.

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion, you've rejected the word that is *exactly* analogous and appropriate.

At least with respect to the scenario outlined in the question, as *clothes* is to *clothed*, so to is *feathers* to ***feathered***.

Even if we were looking at the dictionary definition of *feathered*, "a very light cover or a fringe" is not what it means in this sense.

From Merriam-Webster's definition of [**feathered**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/feathered):

> **1** : having feathers
>     // … misidentified as … a flying reptile, not a *feathered* dinosaur…
>     — Luis M. Chiappe
>     // referring to birds as "our *feathered* friends"
> **2** : covered or decorated with feathers
>     // He was a big man, and in his costume— … *feathered* anklets, *feathered* gauntlets, beaded headband … —he seemed magnified in every dimension, almost a spirit-being.
>     — Ian Frazier
>     // From this region come the magnificent beadwork art, the buckskin garments, the great *feathered* war bonnet, and the concept of long fringed shirts.
>     — Frederick J. Dockstader

However, in point of fact, we should not be looking at the dictionary definition of *feathered*. As far as this creature is concerned, that's beside the point. Just as it doesn't understand our use of *clothed* because it doesn't wear clothes, we (analogously) shouldn't be imposing our own use of *feathered* on its language—because we don't have feathers.

If *clothed* is appropriate to us, but meaningless to it, then it doesn't matter if *feathered* is ***not*** appropriate to us. Whatever  it wears or has, the adjectival equivalent of that noun is appropriate to it.

Luckily though, *feathered* actually is meaningful, even by our definition of the word.

Comment: Indeed, our **feathered friends** and humans "feather their nest."

Comment: I have a difficulty with "feathered in down" - the figurative meaning and the literal meaning are too close to be "poetic" - "down" is a type of feather. It is rather like saying "it was painted in paint."